# List object conversion to integer

Tags: python, list, object

I have a list:

```
nums=[[19],[5],[23],[6],[10]].
```

Is there a way to convert a list object to a "simple" object?

So `[19]` would become the actual integer `19`? Maybe some type of casting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is probably the most clear approach:

```
nums = [[19],[5],[23],[6],[10]]

ints = [i[0] for i in nums]
```

---

There are other instructive ways to do it as well.

Unpacking from the item works (which makes clear that there's only one element in each item, and will give an unpacking error if there is more than one):

```
unpacked_ints = [i for i, in nums]
```

Or can pop from each sublist (the last item, which removes it from the sublist, it will no longer be there if you keep around a reference to the sublists):

```
popped_ints = [i.pop() for i in nums]
```

or functionally (`operator.itemgetter` returns a partial function like `lambda x: x[0]`):

```
import operator
ints2 = list(map(operator.itemgetter(0), nums))
```

in Python2, no need for list to materialize:

```
import operator
ints3 = map(operator.itemgetter(0), nums)
```

---

EDIT in response to comment:

Now your comment is that you're dealing with a big iterable, probably don't want to materialize the whole thing in memory. That still doesn't change how I'd recommend you deal with it. I get the sense you'd like to be able to do this:

```
for i in nums:
    my_process(i)
```

So I would recommend you do this:

```
for i in nums:
    my_process(i[0])
```

Comment: I need to convert specific elements and NOT iterate. If I iterate, the whole idea loses its meaning because we are talking about big datasets. I yet haven't found a way to convert specific elements. Any ideas?

Comment: @alex777 See my final note at the end of my post. Regarding converting elements: you can't coerce a list holding a single element to that element in the same way you can coerce a string to an int to a float and back. But you can do what's been suggested by pretty much each answer, just avoid materializing the entire iterable.

Answer (score 4):

Another option would be to flatten the list.

```
nums = [[19],[5],[23],[6],[10]]
nums = [num for numlist in nums for num in numlist]
```

Or, but only if you want to irritate anybody reading your code:

```
n = [[19],[5],[23],[6],[10]]
n = [n for n in n for n in n]
```

;)

Comment: I like the answer but for the shake of the potential code reader, I won't do that!! +1 though

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is in stdlib: https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable

```
import itertools
nums=[[19],[5],[23],[6],[10]]
print list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(nums))
# [19, 5, 23, 6, 10]
```

Comment: My solution does exactly what other posted solution do. If you want to 'flatten' only the first element, `nums[0] = nums[0][0]` should do the work. Is it what you want? In the future, it is good to post your expected output in your question, to avoid misunderstandings.